# output of stored procedure should come in single line

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Following is my Query which given output in multiple Lines I want in a single line

```
create table #temptable
 (userid int,UserName nvarchar(50),WardId bigint,ZoneId bigint,WardName nvarchar(255))
 insert into #temptable    
 exec GetWardWiseHierarchyUser  @wardid --354 
 SELECT distinct WardId FROM #temptable

 declare @StringWardId nvarchar(max)
 select   @StringWardId=(select  stuff((select  ',' + cast(wardId as nvarchar(50)) from #temptable
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1,'' ))
```

This SP giving Following Output

```
WardId
10054
10056
10057
10058
```

But I want this output like

```
WardId
10054,10056,10057,10058
```

Please Help me to solve this problem

Comment: You've tagged this MySQL but that clearly appears to be SQL Server code, what database are you using?

Comment: i am using sql server management studio.please help me to solve this problem

Comment: What is the result of second query (ie) `@StringWardId`

Comment: result of second query is my fist output which is coming in row wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COALESCE only replace null to ' '

```
DECLARE @WardId VARCHAR(8000) 
    SELECT @WardId = COALESCE(@WardId + ', ', '') + WardId
    FROM tbl
```